# R - paste complex stylised values from list

Tags: r

I am working with severals lists, and each list contains a large number of data frames. Each data frame contains 3 variables (`cluster`, `grp`, `value`), such as (example of 1 list)

```
$`0`
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  cluster   grp               value
    (int) (int)               (chr)
1       1     0 c Personal Care-277

$`1`
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  cluster   grp      value
    (int) (int)      (chr)
1       1     1 b Unpaid-1

$`2`
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  cluster   grp             value
    (int) (int)             (chr)
1       1     2 c Personal Care-1
```

What I would like is to summarise these informations in a vector in order to analyse them easily [**output wanted**] :

```
cluster 1 : (c Personal Care-277) - (b Unpaid-1) - (c Personal Care-1)
```

What I have tried to do is the following :

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
```

1) I first merged all the data frame together by `cluster`. I choose to use `join_all` which seems to work fine for the job, except the strange `colname` output.

```
dt1 = dt %>% lapply(fgr) %>% 
  join_all(by = 'cluster') %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("cluster", paste('t', 1:3, sep = '')))
```

2) Then I used `paste` to put the values in a stylised fashion together

```
dt1 %>% 
  mutate(print = paste('cluster: ', cluster, ' (' , t1, ')', '(', t2 , ')', '(',    t3 , ')', sep="") ) %>% 
  select(print)

#                                                             print
# 1 cluster: 1 (c Personal Care-277)(b Unpaid-1)(c Personal Care-1)
```

The problem is that I have many different lists with many dataframes and some dataframes have unequal `length`. Here the list in example has 3 elements `t1` `t2` `t3` (plus the `cluster`). But some list have dataframes with 4 or more elements.

**Questions**

I wanted to know first if there was a way to automate this `paste`, in order to avoid writing `t1`, `t2`, and so on **by hand** and secondly if you had any better idea for a routine than the one I showed here.

Thanks

**The data (list)**

```
dt = list(structure(list(cluster = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
  grp = structure(1L, .Label = "0", class = "factor"), value = structure(1L, .Label = "c Personal Care-277", class = "factor")), .Names = c("cluster", 
"grp", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
structure(list(cluster = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    grp = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(1L, .Label = "b Unpaid-1", class = "factor")), .Names =     c("cluster", 
   "grp", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
  structure(list(cluster = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    grp = structure(1L, .Label = "2", class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(1L, .Label = "c Personal Care-1", class = "factor")),    .Names = c("cluster", 
  "grp", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your dput output is giving errors `Error in structure(list(cluster = 1L, grp = 0L, value = "c Personal Care-277"),  : 
  object 'cluster' not found`

Comment: Based on the expected output, perhaps `bind_rows(dt) %>% summarise(value = paste(value, collapse=" - ")) %>% .$value`

Comment: @akrun the data should be fixed now thanks

Comment: @akrun your `row_bind` solution is good. However, we lose the `cluster` number which is important in the output.

Comment: You can use the group_by statement.

Comment: stupid question but I have actually long printed sequences and I can't print them completely. The `paste` sequence cut a the end of my screen instead of continuing on a second line ?? any clue ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the `options(width = 200)` or so

Comment: perfect thanks a lot. Works. I think that I will actually use a threshold a relevant value to display. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(dt) %>% 
        group_by(cluster) %>% 
        summarise(new = paste0('cluster: ', unique(cluster), ' (', paste(value, collapse = ','), ')')) %>% 
        select(new)

# A tibble: 1 × 1
#                                                            new
#                                                          <chr>
#1 cluster: 1 (c Personal Care-277,b Unpaid-1,c Personal Care-1)
```

Comment: I used this one finally to be precise `summarise(new = paste0('cluster: ', unique(cluster), paste(' (', value, ')', collapse = ' -')))`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(dt)[, sprintf("cluster: %s (%s)", unique(cluster), 
        paste(unique(value), collapse=')(')),  by = cluster]$V1
#[1] "cluster: 1 (c Personal Care-277)(b Unpaid-1)(c Personal Care-1)"
```